# Displaying status on a popup

Tags: javascript, popup

I want to use the status bar for displaying some information on some created popups, but it looks like it can't be displayed in a popup as it can be done on the principal page window:

I mean I use this to create the popup:

```
popup=window.open("","popup1","width=300, height=200, status=yes, resizable=yes");
popup.status="Some info";
```

But it always displays blank, even an alert(popup.status displays blank).

But for the principal window, window.status displays fine, so it looks like the problem is more about the popup than about the status property.

Is there something that can be done so it shows as in a principal window?

Comment: Some of the properties of window.open() are from the past when IE reigned supreme and no longer valid/supported by modern browsers except maybe Edge.

Answer (score 0):

I had no idea what you mean by status so i tried google. And this is what i found

**This property does not work in default configuration of IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari or Opera 15+**

So i would try to find different solution for your issue.